# Activity Indicator does not change visible property and show whole page

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, loading

I'm developing a xamarin forms app and I wanted to add to show "loading" states. But I'm facing that problem right now. When I open that page this bottom stacklayout shown but it never change anything and not show the my main page.

XAML :

```
ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:İdaServis.ViewModels"
         x:Class="İdaServis.View.SamplePage">

<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:SamplePageViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<ContentPage.Content >
    <StackLayout >
        <Label Text="Sample Page"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

       
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>

<StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding Isloading}"   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center" >
    <Label Text="Yükleniyor..." TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" />

    <ActivityIndicator  Color="SpringGreen"  IsRunning="True" />
</StackLayout>
```

I write viewodel like this:

```
public class SamplePageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private bool _isloading, showPage;
    
    public SamplePageViewModel ()
    {
        _isloading = true;
        showPage = false;
        manageLoadings();
    }

    private async void manageLoadings()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2500);
        _isloading = false;
        showPage = true;
        OnPropertyChanged();

    }

    public bool Isloading { get => _isloading; set { _isloading = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

    public bool ShowPage { get => showPage; set { showPage = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found very simple method to achive this "loading popup". I'm going to use UserDialogs nuget package.

To show pop up :

```
UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Loading...");
```

To hide pop up :

```
UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
```

You can use this code before api calls then hide it when you get result.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the IsRunning property

```
<ActivityIndicator IsRunning="true" />
```

Also check the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/activityindicator

Answer (score 0):

You did not set the right `OnPropertyChanged` method.

First, you need to set the name for the OnPropertyChanged method like this `OnPropertyChanged("Isloading");`.

Here is the right code you can refer to:

```
  public bool Isloading { get => _isloading; set { _isloading = value; OnPropertyChanged("Isloading"); } }

  public bool ShowPage { get => showPage; set { showPage = value; OnPropertyChanged("ShowPage"); } }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
```

Second, you should modify the `Isloading` instead of the `_isloading`, also the `ShowPage`.

Here is the right code:

```
  private async void manageLoadings()
  {
      await Task.Delay(2500);
      Isloading = false;
      ShowPage = true;
      OnPropertyChanged();

  }
```

> hen I open that page this bottom stacklayout shown but it never change
> anything and not show the my main page.

You need to put all the `StackLayouts` in the `ContentPage.Content` and do not put the elements outside the ContentPage.Content. The ContentPage can only be set once, if you set the elements out side the `ContentPage.Content`, it will cover the elements in the old `ContentPage.Content`.

Here is the code you can refer to:

```
  <ContentPage.Content >

      <StackLayout>
          <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding ShowPage}">
              <Label Text="Sample Page"
                 VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                 HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
              <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
          </StackLayout>
          <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding Isloading}"   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center" >
              <Label Text="Yükleniyor..." TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" />

              <ActivityIndicator  Color="SpringGreen"  IsRunning="True" />
          </StackLayout>
       </StackLayout> 
      
  </ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: Sorry but this does not fix problem. Still bottom stacklayouts isvisible property not change.

Comment: I updated the answer and you can check the code.

Comment: I have tried this, I want activity indicator work overlay that page like a pop up. You divide page 2 pieces and 1 of them is loading screen 1 of them is my main page. I dont want this style. I researched some and find UserDialogs has loading popup. I used this one. I'll write an answer for my question. Thank you for your fast answer and efforts.

Comment: You are welcome. If you still have the question, you can post it directly.